# What security issues could occur when generating ids on the client?

Tags: api, ids, rest

It's sometimes convenient to generate ids client-side in a typical CRUD app.

The main benefit is for optimistic updates: you can update your client state with the right id without waiting for the response.

**Examples:**

- The id is used in some kind of relationship. Say "create author for this book", and the authorId is directly set in the book optimistically, no need to refetch anything.
- A list input in a form: each item has an id, stored in the form state. When submitting the form, we want the ids in the form state to be exactly the ones of a database if we do a deep compare to show a "reset changes" button.

**Now given that:**

- ids are generated using as much bits of entropy as reasonable
- the server validates that the id looks like an uuid

**What security issues if any could occur in this case?**

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that a conflict might arise with existing ids in the database for other items. Depending on the details of the application this might allow the client to retrieve data which do not belong to the client or overwrite existing data in the database. Even if the attacker is not able to guess other ids they might deliberately confuse your application logic by creating multiple entries with the same id.

> ids are generated using as much bits of entropy as reasonable

The server has no way to verify that this is actually true. It would have to believe the client side, which should not be done unless the server has sufficient control over the client side to make sure what code got executed to generate the id.

Note that just providing the code to the client does not help to ensure this, since it cannot be guaranteed that the client used this code to generate the id in the first place and also did not modify it afterwards.

> the server validates that the id looks like an uuid

This does not ensure either that the supposed new id does not conflict with existing ids in the database.

The only way to ensure that a client side id does not conflict with existing ids is to check for this on the server side. This might be done in application logic, but databases might also enforce this if UNIQUE constraints are used.

Apart from that there are attacks against assumptions about the ids made in your application. It looks like your application assumes random ids. An attacker might construct ids which look random with the checks you have implemented but which are actually deliberately designed to affect the performance of your application - see for example [Denial of Service via Algorithmic Complexity Attacks](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Emcw/Teaching/refs/misc/denial-of-service.pdf) for more on this.

Comment: I get your point, obviously there would be a unique constraint in the database. If there is a collision this would be an API error. If there are many API errors it's the client's fault not to make its ids random enough. Let's say the client is *well* implemented. I don't see any security breach. Hackers could create their own items, they would still know only their ids, not others.

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon: *"Let's say the client is well implemented."* - does not matter. You cannot be sure that the server got the new id from this client and not some attacker. *"Hackers could create their own items, they would still know only their ids, not others."* - they could create any id, including ids which already exist in the system.  They could create ids which are not actually random but are design to affect the performance of your system - see [algorithmic complexity attacks](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~mcw/Teaching/refs/misc/denial-of-service.pdf)

Comment: For uniqueness garanteed by the database, there isn't any possible algorithmic complexity attack I think. It's just about descending a btree index to find out if the value is already used. Then "server validates that the id looks like an uuid" needs to be precised. If it's a regex, yes regex can create denial of service, let's say it just checks the length. This is true for any validated input anyway. I still don't see any security issue intrinsic to client-side generated ids.

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon: hash tables, btrees, ... as used in databases for indices and to ensure uniqueness - all have worst case behavior. And that's what algorithmic complexity attacks are designed to produce.

Comment: I'd be happy to have any reference on this. If this is true it means any user input checked against uniqueness in the database is a potential source of denial of service, like unique email or username on sign up. It's hard to believe.

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon: there is a difference between checking uniqueness against existing entries and mass-inserting new keys. The first is a lookup on some dataset which is hopefully optimized for lookup (i.e. less than linear lookup time). The latter is adding lots of new data to the dataset, which means that the dataset needs to be optimized again (like tree balancing). With the right data one might try to hit the worst-case for optimizing - whereas random data are usually best case. This is probably only relevant when mass inserting data, not when inserting a few.